# Call a remote WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good evening, 
I am new in c# and asp.net
I have created an MVC 4 WEB Application and I am using aspx as the view.
I am trying to call a remote web API and unfortunately I do not get it, in order to display the data on my web site.
I created one controller and inside the controller in the Index() method I wrote this code:

```
public class CallAPIController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /CallAPI/

   public async Task<string> Index()
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://remoteWEBAPI/");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/data").Result;  // Blocking call!
       string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("Content: " + json);
            return json;

    }

}
```

I am new to this technologies, I have tried many things and I have been struggling with this for the last 4-5 hours.I do not know how to solve this problem. Could you please help me? I do not think it should be very difficult for someone expert familiar with these...

Comment: What is the **problem** you've actually encountered? This is not an aswerable question.

Comment: Your code looks OK are you getting an exception is response.IsSuccessStatusCode true ?

Comment: I made some changes on my code and now I have the above code. the next step is how to display the data in my web site(in order to check if I get the correct data from the web API)? how I can call this method from my view(aspx)?

Comment: I do not get any exception or error on the above code. Thanks  Ondrej Tucny and – SzabV for reply to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your WebAPI accepts `GET` method and returning a JSON string.

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

        string returnedString = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://yourwebapi.com/api/data"));
```

Comment: Good evening kkocabiyik and thanks for answered me! :) the above code where I supposed to write it? inside a controller, a view? I know this question is annoying but I am new on MVC web application.

Comment: you need to write it into your controller where you already wrote HttpClient

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. and after that, how I can check if I get the data? what I should write into the view in order to call this method?

Comment: returnedString variable should contained the returned data

Comment: I really appreciate your help..,But I was little confused.., I want to display this string to my web site.from this function I get the string,but how I can display it to my web site? I do not know how I can achieved this...,

Comment: Below lines type ViewBag.ReturnedString = returnedString. and in your View  type ViewBag.ReturnedString

Comment: Hi   kkocabiyik! I WOULD LIKE TO THANK YOU! ! ! ! !  you save me a lot of time.!it works! really thanks! :)